# how can i get data from webpage without webbrowser or chromedriver

Tags: html, vb.net

i used **chromedriver** but its slowly,i tried webbrowser but not worked.

My webpage is;

`**https://coinmarketcap.com/converter/btc/usd/?amt=1  **`

so
i want get of how much usd one bitcoin or more then one

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Coinmarketcap uses it's own API service. You can use their API instead of using web page. Dont forget to add Newtonsoft library to your project from Nuget.

```
    Dim btcAmount = 4
    Dim tempcookies As New CookieContainer
    Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
    Dim postreq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/data-api/v3/tools/price-conversion?amount=" & btcAmount & "&convert_id=2781&id=1"), HttpWebRequest)
    postreq.Method = "GET"
    postreq.KeepAlive = True
    postreq.CookieContainer = tempcookies
    postreq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729"
    postreq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    postreq.Referer = "https://coinmarketcap.com"
    Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse
    postresponse = DirectCast(postreq.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
    tempcookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies)
    Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())
    Dim result As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd
    Dim json As JObject = JObject.Parse(result)
    MessageBox.Show(json.Item("data").Item("quote")(0).Item("price"))
```

Comment: thanks for all its worked :))

Comment: can i add something my question please?
 how can i find `Dim btcAmount = 4`  which coin number*

Comment: https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyCategories

İ Read this page 
then write api command like this ;
https://api.coinmarketcap.com/data-api/v3/tools/price-conversion?amount=1&convert_id=825&symbol=BTC
then igot an error like this
{"status":{"timestamp":"2021-11-09T19:21:29.868Z","error_code":"500","error_message":"The system is busy, please try again later!","elapsed":"0","credit_count":0}}